# How to run a GEF application in RAP runtime

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, equinox, eclipse-gef, eclipse-rap

I have a GEF application and want to run it in RAP runtime. I have set the target definition adding the GEF dependencies. But, somehow the IDE didn't manage to found GEF library. I used the plug-in this link provide http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/incubator/nightly/gef/ .

Am I missing something?

One more thing, 
what I have understood so far is that I only need to set the target platform into RAP runtime. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks,

Andrei Dharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow managed to find this hidden example in RAP GEF Incubator site. Here's the link: https://github.com/eclipse/rap.incubator.gef/tree/master/bundles/org.eclipse.rap.gef.demo

Big thanks to Austin Riddle for creating the only example I can find on the internet.